# How to change tag <br /> to <p> in blogger?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, blogger

Look at the source code of a blogger page, I noticed that they look like 2 or 3 of the tag `<br/>` for each paragraph.

Would it be possible to change it to `<p>` with some css or script technique?

Searching on these tags I found this article where it says it is not to use it, look http://wbruno.com.br/html/semantica-da-tag-br/

I found this code

```
br {content: ""; display: block; margin: 1rem 0; }
br :: after {content: "› "; / * content: "" space ignored * /; float: left; margin-right: 0.5rem; }
```

is it meant to do that?

Comment: It is not possible because `<br />` is a line-break without end tag. The paragraph `<p>......</p>` always has an end tag. You cannot put the `</p>` in the code simply because it is unknown where to place it.

Comment: look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275250/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-html-with-multiple-br-tags-into-proper-surrou

Comment: looks like a configuration from a text/content/page editor used in the administration side of the site.  see on blogger support/forum if you can/how to modify this

Comment: looks like the configuration per post is gone and now the new editor enforces `<p>`... hopefully that will be for good...

Answer (score 0):

Although it would technically be possible, what is the intended purpose?  I'm not familiar with Blogger code, but I assume the `<br />` tag is intended for element division.  What is your reasoning for switching out the `<br />` tag for the `<p></p>` tag?

The `<p></p>` tag is intended to markup the page with paragraph text.  Changing the `<br />` tag just to change it will add unnecessary code that has to be rendered.

```
$(function replaceText(){
    $('br').replaceWith('<p></p>');
});

replaceText();
```

Comment: Well I read an article that says not to use this tag in too much.

And whenever I use 1 <p> in any article, when I post it is replaced by <br /> <br /> <br />

3 tags

Comment: It looks like Blogger automatically replaces <p> tags with <br/>

Comment: That makes more sense and is frustrating.  If you can upload a JavaScript file or jQuery, you can swap the <br /> tags with <p></p>.  The only issue is every <br /> tag will have to become <p></p>.  Are you using the code editor or the wisiwig editor?

Comment: I have jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js at the end of the blogger head tag

Comment: That will pull in the jQuery library.  You will need to add a custom script in order to edit the jQuery.  If they don't allow uploading js files, there isn't any way to edit the javascript.

Comment: I can add script tag by html page, that's where I add several scripts

Comment: Try the edit above.  You will need to load this after your body tag.

Comment: It didn't work, I'm sorry, I don't think Blogger lets you do that with scripts.

It's a shame because I believe this harms the site as these codes are unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I am able to replace `<br/> <br>` to `<p> </p>` by the help of jQuery.

HTML

```
<div>
<p>blah blah blah<br/>* blah blah blah<br/>* blah blah blah<br/>* blah blah blah</p>
</div>
<div>
<p>blah blah blah<br>* blah blah blah<br>* blah blah blah<br>* blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function()
{$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</p><p>"));});
```

Here is the link attached https://jsfiddle.net/Arpit09/tgxc3y8d/5/

I am not familiar with how blogger works, this is just a jQuery script to convert `<br/>` tag to `<p></p>`. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: What if the `<br>` is in a `<li>` or other tag. This will result in a strange layout effect. It is possible with Javascript / jQuery but not with a 2-liner.

Comment: I tried and it didn't work <script>

$(function()
{$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/<br>\\*/g,"</p><p>"));});

</script>

Comment: It didn't work, I'm sorry, I don't think Blogger lets you do that with scripts.

It's a shame because I believe this harms the site as these codes are unnecessary